# How to export a class diagram in StarUML?

Tags: uml, staruml

I'm modelling a system with other colleagues and we're using StarUML.
Each person has your own .mdj project with a class diagram on it.

Now we want to export each class diagram and import them all in a single project. We've tried to use **Export | Fragment** (exporting the model folder where the diagram is) and importing it on the main .mdj project but all diagram's objects are corrupted and only some associations appear.

**How can we import all the diagrams in a single .mdj project?**